# Javascript not printing within php loop

Tags: javascript, php

new to php and javascript. I am trying to print an id using javascript within a php loop and nothing is turning up. Here is the code:

```php
$sql = "SELECT dueDate, assignmentName, className FROM assignments INNER JOIN classes ON assignments.class = classes.id ORDER BY DATE(dueDate)";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Assignments";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<div class="popup" id="popup">';
      echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
      echo '<div class = "content">' . $row['dueDate'] . $row['className'] . '</div>';
      echo '<div class="close-btn content" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>';
      echo '<div class = "btn-group">' . '<button onclick="togglePopup()">' . $row['assignmentName'] . '</button>' . '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">  document.write(printID()); </script>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to understand, where JavaScript and PHP are executed. PHP will be executed on the server side while JavaScript is executed on the client side (mostly a browser). If you understand this, you know why JavaScript will not be executed on the server side.

Comment: What is the actual HTML that is generated? Where is the *printID* function defined or initialised? The use of *document.write* is strongly discouraged.

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quotation marks inside of single quotation marks.

Comment: no html is generated, and the printID function is defined in my script.js which is linked at the top of my code (I know it is linked I have other items of script that run). I was using document.write for testing. I really want to link my php and javascript because I want to increment something within my loop. I was using this to test because i dont think it is linking at all.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, what is the HTML that the PHP is generating? Post a **minimal** example, including the *printID* function. Remember that the *document.write* statement will run as the page loads and you will probably have multiple elements with id "popup", depending on how many times the while loop iterates.

Comment: I have gotten it to work! I do not know what was wrong with it but it is now working. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not clearly identified the problem and has apparently fixed it without posting either a cause or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you want PHP to know, what `printID()` is and what it should do. PHP knows nothing about JavaScript functions, because JavaScript and PHP are executed on totally different places. PHP renders your HTML and sends a response to your browser, which executes JavaScript. JavaScript will not be executed, when PHP is processing data.

There 's one thing you could do. Wait until everything is rendered and execute your JavaScript functions at the end of your HTML before the `</body>` tag.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.popup');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, (element) => {
        let id = printID();
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(id));
    });
});
```

What does the above code snippet? It waits and will be executed, until all DOM is loaded. Then it searches for all elements with the css class named "popup". By the way there is another issue in your code. You 're processing your database query result with a loop and you 're using an id attribute. Id attributes should only be used once in your markup. So please use a css class instead of an id attribute. When using a class names "popup" you can read out all elements and execute your javascript function `printID()` and append a new element. That 's it.

Your failure is, that you didn 't recognize, that JavaScript is a client side language and is not executed by php. Even when it 's written in an html template.

### A possible better approach

As you said you want to change a parameter in your `togglePopup` JavaScript function. The following code shows up a possible solition.

```
<?php
...
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="popup">';
    echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
    echo '<div class = "content">' . $row['dueDate'] . $row['className'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="close-btn content">&times;</div>';
    echo '<div class = "btn-group">' . '<button id="popup-' . $i . '">' . $row['assignmentName'] . '</button>' . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    $i++;
}
```

Instead of placing onclick attributes just leave this out. Instead place an id parameter on the button element. Keep in mind, that tha value of a id parameter has to be unique. Instead of using an id attribute, you can use a data attribute like `data-id="my-value"`. Data attributes ensure, that the value of this attribute has not to be unique. Just to show you to possible ways ...

At the end of your HTML before the `</body>` tag place the following.

```
<script>
    const togglePopup = (event) => {
        let target = event.target;
        let id = target.getAttribute('id');

        // do something with the id attribute
    }
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.popup button[id^="popup-"]');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, (element) => {
            element.addEventListener('click', togglePopup);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This small snippet adds a click event handler to every button inside an element with the class `.popup` which has an id attribute which begins with `popup-`. When this button will be clicked the togglePopup function will be called. Inside this function the id attribute comes from the target element.

With this solution you keep your html markup clean and all javascript stuff is separated from the php code.

Comment: yes that is actually what I am trying to use the script function to appropriately change the popup id in order to match which loop is going on. I was able to get the script function to run with my original code but I am currently working on changing the function to update the popup id.

Comment: `function togglePopup(){
    document.getElementById("popup1").classList.toggle("active");
  }` this is my code for the togglePopup() which is why I have been trying to change the popup id (I am not done modifying this code either obviously I will need to modify "popup1" accordingly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sure there are better ways. Just give your button element an id attribute or pass an id parameter when you call the `togglePopup` function. If you use my first suggestion, you can use the buttom element click event to get the id attribute from the event element. If you use my second suggestion you can use the parameter directly in your function by passing it on function call.

Comment: wouldn't I run into the same issue though? The button id would still be inside the loop? (all the buttons are inside this while loop) I believe I need a different id for each button because they each have different content.

Comment: That 's it. You need different id attribute values. I 've edited my answer with a possible solution.